# DNN7 Populate Dropownlist Of Registration Page in Dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am new in Dotnetnuke.

I Have a Question About DNN Custom Registration form.
I have created a custom registration form and Added DropDownList on Form of DataType List and Added Entries In It.It showing that DropDownList.

Now My Problem is that; I Need to Populate this DropDownList from Db table .So How It is Possible in DNN7. Thank You..!!!

Comment: @ChrisHammond is correct about the List table.  I use this extensively, but there is a bug in it that I have registered: https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-25763 .  You will be able to have these items show up in your database, but you will not be able to search on this item using the Account Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to populate it from a LIST in DNN, or use a custom registration module of some sort, the registration in DNN doesn't provide a way to pull data from other tables for the registration process.